# Does "rollercoaster" in this phrase mean "a dramatically change in movie plots"?

Tags: word-meaning

> a nonstop action rollercoaster filled with amazing stunts and spectacular special effects

It can't be a real roller coaster, maybe some unpredictably exciting action part in a movie?

Not quite sure, but not far-off, I guess.

Is it a metaphorical use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is from the [OxfordDictionaries' example](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/special-effect) for the phrase 'special effect'.

True, it's not [an actual roller coaster (#1)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/roller-coaster) but [something that changes very quickly (2)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/roller-coaster). Furthermore, the word *roller coaster* is beyond its traditional usage and has been widely used for something that excites us, adds thrill or the like.

It seems a noun phrase *a nonstop-action-rollercoaster (movie) filled with...* and it talks about several jaw-dropping stunt scenes and special effects. The roller-coaster stunts are also possible.

[Check this.](http://www.msgvarsity.com/new-jersey/hasbrouck-heights-cheering-team-better-than-ever-1.1150661)

> The new stunts in the team’s routine include the “rollercoaster” stunts from the movie Rollercoaster stunt in “Bring it On,” and from all-star teams including a pyramid.